# Using HDInsight with encrypted data

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-hdinsight, hipaa

I'm considering using HDInsight to process data that must be encrypted at rest. I'm still in the early research phase, but I assume I can add a map step that does the decryption.

Am I way off base here, or is this a viable path forward?

Also, what is the protocol that's used internally to communicate the results of previous map/reduce operations? Does this have the option of being encrypted in motion?

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight is 100% Apache Hadoop-based service in the cloud. You can find the answers/suggestions by searching Hadoop+Encription on stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hadoop+encryption

Comment: It may be 100% compatible, but given the fact it's Hadoop-as-service, I'm sure I don't have most of the options outlined in general hadoop questions.